# How to read line by line with universal newline support in c?

Tags: c, newline, fgets

```
int n = NMAXVAL;
char line[MAXLINE];
int rowCount = 0;
char* token = NULL;

while (rowCount < n && fgets(line, MAXLINE, stdin))
{
    token = strtok(line, " ");
    checkToken(token, n);
    // do something
    rowCount++;
}
```

My function reads from stdin line by line and performs some tasks. It works fine for me on Visual Studio. However, it acts differently on xcode. It took a while for me to realize that this is caused by the difference between `\n`, `\r`, and `\n\r`. How do I make my code support these newline chars?

update:
consider this input:

```
1
10
3 4
5 6 7
```

On visual studio, the function reads line by line. However, on Xcode it reads the first line just fine then it reads \n instead 10\n.

Comment: You can add `\r` and `\n` to the token separator in `strtok` : `token = strtok(line, " \r\n");` to ignore them.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input .

Comment: I'm not aware a system that uses the `\n\r` sequence.  Windows uses `\r\n` natively (and so do many internet protocols), and the standard I/O library on Windows maps `\r\n` to just newline when the file is processed as a text file.   Old Macs (essentially those from the last millennium, not those running any version of macOS X) used just `\r`.  There is no universal line ending; there is no standard C function that handles all line endings.

Comment: If you are tokenizing on whitespace, why do you care about line boundaries at all?  Surely you aren't parsing a language in which `\t`, `\n`, and `\r` are not treated the same as a space.  The only languages that do that are intentionally designed to be pathological.

Comment: @user3121023 stdin

Comment: The full classic whitespace characters are " \r\n\f\t\v" as [isspace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On visual studio, the function reads line by line. However, on xcode it reads the first line just fine then it reads \n instead 10\n.

The problem is not `fgets()`.  This problem is the same exact file is treated as different *text files* on different platforms.

A simply solution is to create each text file, separately, on each platform using that platform's end-of-line convention.

Alternatively and harder, to read the same exact file on different platforms,  create your own line read function that ID's an end-of-line in the various ways.  Depending on goals, code may need to (re-)open the file in binary.

Alternatively and meets many cases, open the file in *text mode* (as `stdin` does), use `fgets()` and strip various line endings off.

```
if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
  line[strcspn(line, "\n\r")] = '\0'; // truncate after first of \n, \r or \0
}
```